# Kmeans fit_predict with word2vec

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, word2vec

I am trying to cluster my word vectors using kmeans as described [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-3-more-fun-with-word-vectors). 
The code snippet I am using

```
# Set "k" (num_clusters) to be 1/5th of the vocabulary size, or an
# average of 5 words per cluster
word_vectors = model.syn0
num_clusters = word_vectors.shape[0] / 5

# Initalize a k-means object and use it to extract centroids
kmeans_clustering = KMeans( n_clusters = num_clusters )
idx = kmeans_clustering.fit_predict( word_vectors )
```

I am getting the following error
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Could someone please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the error. Number of clusters must be an integer so I did the following

num_clusters = int(word_vectors.shape[0] / 5)

Comment: UGGGGH!  Thank you!  I feel so dumb not spotting the same cause of the error in my own code :P

Comment: Nope. Mistakes happen and that is ok ( not dumb)  as long as we acknowledge, learn and move forward :D

Comment: You could use wordVectors.shape[0] // 5 too. The // operator force division result to int